# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol utils when trying to migrate CSipSimple

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using [CSipSimple](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/). I followed the migration guide from Eclipse to Android Studio carefully and the only error that I am getting is

> cannot resolve symbol **utils**

and is happening on below lines:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.utils.UtilityWrapper;
import com.csipsimple.R;
```

In `build.gradle`, I have added the following line:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
}
```

Does anyone know why this would be happening? Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is deprecated. No more development will be taking place.

Comment: it is better to use `ActionBar` from support library

Comment: I am using CSIpSimple project . It is their code .

Answer (score 1):

[ActionBarSherlock-4.4](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/4.4.0/actionbarsherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal) does not have the package `utils`.
Check the version that was used before migrating to Android Studio.

Comment: Which version of ActionBarSherlock contains package utils ? please tell me

Comment: ActionBarSherlock-4.4 is the latest version . It must have utils package .

Comment: @osimerpothe there is not utils in V4.4, are you using `csipsimple` by any chance?

Comment: Yes , I am using csipsimple . What is the problem ?

Comment: `csipsimple` uses customised actionbarsherlock, infact **actionbarsherlock** never had `UtilityWrapper `

Comment: Then what will I write in dependencies for customised actionbarsherlock ?

Comment: Please tell : What will I write in dependencies for customised actionbarsherlock ?  @VenomVendor

Comment: Check out `https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/checkout` and add the missing utils. If not remove `UtilityWrapper` implementation from your code & do the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[VenomVendor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34265345/2821954) already provides the reason: there's no `UtilityWrapper` on ActionBarSherlock. So, I'll try to provide the fix instead.

---

tqcenglish has a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tqcenglish/CSipSimple) for Android Studio port for CSipSimple. Its readme says:

> **Change**
>
> - /res/values/wizard_sipgate_string.xml
>
>   ```
>   <string  xm:lns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/tools" /> -
>   <resources xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/tools"/> +
>   ```
> - delete `jni` folder
> - add `jniLibs` folder and `org.pjsip.pjsua` to `java` folder
> - delete about quote `UtilityWrapper`
>
> **Reference**
>
> com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar

This seems to give a hint of removing any reference to `UtilityWrapper`, including `import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.utils.UtilityWrapper;`. However, it might compromise something.

You're on the right path to use `com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar` for the dependency.

---

Alternatively, I don't see any reasons why files under `utils` won't work outside of `com.actionbarsherlock.internal` package, so you should be able to copy all files from [com.actionbarsherlock.internal.utils](https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/source/browse/trunk/ActionBarSherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/?r=1741#internal%2Futils) to your `java` folder, then replace the `import` statement to use the corresponding package.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error while trying to use OpenCV, import this:

```
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
```